# Conditional expectation of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real-valued random variables. The conditional expectation of X condion on $Y$ taking value $y$ is defined as

$$
E[X | Y=y] = \int x \, p_{X | Y}(x | y) dx.
$$

Let $\sigma(Y)$ be the generated sigma algebra of $Y$.

Is it true that

$$
E[X | Y] \triangleq E[X | \sigma(Y)] = \int x\, p_{X | Y}(x | Y) dx
$$
?

Well intuitively seems yes. E[X | Y] is measurable w.r.t. $\sigma(Y)$, so there must be a function $f(Y) = E[X | Y] $. But can this $f(Y)$ be $\int p_{X | Y}(x | Y) dx
$?

Comment: 1/ $\mathsf E(X\mid Y\,{=}\,y) = \int_\Bbb R x\,p_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,\mathrm d x$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Sorry, that's my typo. Now fixed ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $\ E\big(X|\sigma(Y)\big)\ $ is a $\ \sigma(Y)$-measurable function which satisfies the identity
$$
\int_AE\big(X|\sigma(Y)\big)\,dP=E\big(XI_A\big)\\
$$
for all $\ A\in\sigma(Y)\ $.  By the [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) it is uniquely defined $\ P$-almost everywhere.  Now $\ A\in\sigma(Y)\ $ if and only if $\ A=Y^{-1}(B)\ $ for some measurable $\ B\subseteq\mathbb{R}\ $, so
\begin{align}
E\big(XI_A\big)&=E\big(XI_{Y^{-1}(B)}\big)\\
&=E\big(XI_B(Y)\big)\\
&=\int_B\int xp_{X|Y}(x|y)\,dx\,dF_Y(y)\\
&=\int_A\int xp_{X|Y}(x|Y)\,dx\,dP\ .
\end{align}
Therefore, by the uniqueness theorem,
$$
E\big(X|\sigma(Y)\big)=\int xp_{X|Y}(x|Y)\,dx\ ,
$$
except possibly on a set of probability $0$.