# Expectation expression for a conditional random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

A RV $X\geq 0$ follows a distribution $f_X(x)$. I want to write the conditional expectation of $X$, in terms of $f_X(x)$ and/or $F_X(x)$, condition on $X>c$ where $c$ is a positive constant.
$$E[X|X>c]=?$$
I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137991/conditional-expectation-of-a-random-variable) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721778/conditional-expectation-of-an-exponential-random-variable) but not sure how those can be applioed in the above case. Because I need a general expression for any known $f_X(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E[X|X>c]=\Large\frac {\int_c^{\infty} xf_X(x)dx} {\int_c^{\infty} f_X(x)dx}$.
When there is density you can write  $\frac {\int_{(c,\infty)} xdF_X(x)} {\int_{(c,\infty)} dF_X(x)}$.

Comment: I have a minor question! Should $X$ be required to be a continuous distribution?

Comment: In general it is $\frac {\int_{(c,\infty)} xdF_X(x)} {\int_{(c,\infty)} dF_X(x)}$ @VezenBU

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: So $\int_c^{\infty} xf_X(c)dx=f_X(c)\int_c^{\infty} xdx$ as $f_X(c)$ is not a function of $x$?

Comment: @Frey Sorry about the typos.

Comment: @geetha290krm Got it! It works!